# Print leaf nodes in a binary tree right to left?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I'm looking for an answer for this:

> Find the pseudo code of printing the leaf nodes in a binary tree, from
>   right to left.

I would be glad to hear some ideas. A hint (not a full solution, of course) or a link to a related topic that could assist me in understanding this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Perform a depth-first traversal of the tree, handling the right sub-trees first and printing only the leaf nodes.

The easiest way to implement this is with a recursive function.

```java
void printLeafNodes(BinaryTreeNode* treePtr) {
  if(treePtr.leftChild == null && treePtr.rightChild == null) {
    //This is a leaf node; print its value
  } else {
    //Recurse on right subtree
    if(treePtr.rightChild != null) {
      printLeafNodes(treePtr.rightChild);
    }
    //Recurse on left subtree
    if(treePtr.leftChild != null) {
      printLeafNodes(treePtr.leftChild);
    }
  }
}
```

This page is pretty helpful for visualizing the solution: [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Answer (score 1):

```
void in(node* root){
if(root)
    {   
        if(!root->left && !root->right)
              cout<<root->data<<endl;
        in(root->left);
        in(root->right);
    } }
```

You can do something like this(code in C++).

The idea behind this code is, do inorder traversal/ postorder traversal & check if the left & right children are NULL or not. If it's Null it means it's a leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a recursive method by starting out with passing the method the top level node of a binary tree.

In the pseudocode, I'm assuming that each node is defined with "right" and "left" members that themselves are nodes and a "name" property, to print something about the node. The method could look like this, in no particular language since you said pseudocode:

```
function processNode(parent) {
    if(parent.right = null AND parent.left = null)
        print parent.name
    if(parent.right <> null)
        processNode(parent.right)
    if(parent.left <> null)
        processNode(parent.left)
}
```

Then you would start out with:

```
processNode(topNode)
```

Comment: That code will print non-leaf-nodes and will print leaf nodes twice.

Comment: I see how it would've printed twice. Fixed.

Comment: thank you very much guys! 
i do really appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform in-order traversal and add only leaf nodes to the list of visited nodes.
2. Revert the list.

Or

Actually when creating the list in step one keep adding node at the head and let it point to previous node(rather than previous node pointing to new node).

Answer (score 0):

Print leaf nodes while doing the level order traversal in reverse order excluding the nodes which are not leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Do Inoder/Preorder/postorder But for Right Child First Then go to left Child

```
void postOrder(Node* root)
{
if(root==NULL)
return;
postOrder(root->right);
postOrder(root->left);
if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
cout << root->data <<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know how to traverse a binary tree in order using recursion.

```
void visit(Node node) {
     if(node.hasLeft()) {
         visit(node.getLeft());
     }
     handleValue(node.value); // print or whatever
     if(node.hasRight()) {
         visit(node.getRight());
     }
}
```

You'll notice that when you do this, you're already handling the leaves in left-to-right order, in addition to handling non-leaf nodes.

To visit right-to-left, just reverse the order of the statements -- so visit the right, then handle the value, then visit the left.

To print only leaf nodes, you just need to put an `if` statement around `handleValue`, telling it to only output if the node is a leaf. A node is a leaf if it has neither a left nor right child node.

Answer (score 0):

> python code

```
def Reverse_print(self):
    if self.right:
        self.right.Reverse_print()
    print(self.data),
    if self.left:
        self.left.Reverse_print()
```

it is recursion , it goes always right until there is no right
then at last right it go back to the root print it then print left 
so actually you are printing from biggest value to lowest
then back and so the same thing 
then back and so the same thing 
then back and so the same thing
bla...blaa..blaa

Answer (score -1):

I know that I am resurrecting an old thread but I think that it may help others viewing this thread. If you are talking about interview question, i think that the recursive answer is only a small part of the answer and the interviewer will like to hear the iterative approach as well. The right to left traversal (printing) is not a regular pre/post/inorder traversals that described in wiki. The main idea here is that you need to go right as long as you can and start printing from the far right node first, then its parent and only then the left subtree.

Recursive:

```
printRightToLeft(Node root){
  if (root == null)
     return;

  // You can check root.right and root.left for null before calling the
  // printRightToLeft function to avoid pushing unneeded data to recursion
  // call stack.

  printRightToLeft(root.right);
  if (root.right == null && root.left == null)
     print(root);
  printRightToLeft(root.left);
}
```

Iterative:

```
printRightToLeft(Node root){
  if (root == null)
    return;

  Stack s = new Stack();
  s.push(root);

  while(!s.isEmpty()){
    Node n = s.top();

    if (n.right != null && !n.visited){
      s.push(n.right);
      n.visited = true;
    } else {
      s.pop();

      if (n.right == null && n.left == null)
         print(n);

      if (n.left != null)
         s.push(n.left);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you misunderstood the question.  Only the leaf nodes are supposed to be printed.

Comment: @Sildoreth, you are absolutely right about the misunderstanding of the printing part, and it can be easily fixed, but my main point was that for an interview questions like these it is always a good practice to mention not only the recursive solution but an iterable one as well (and vice versa)

Comment: The recursive solution doesn't need `Node.visited` -- why does the `Stack` version?

Comment: The iterative solution needs "visited" indication for the node, so that when you pop back the node from the stack that you already visited and went right from, you will not go right again but take the left path. Recursive solution does not need it because at each node it splits the recursion to the right wing and left wing without "going back" to the node, so the indication is not needed.

Comment: There are other ways to achieve this, without adding a field to `Node`, and without the algorithm modifying `Node`s as it goes. One option is to have a stack of `Object`, place either a `String` or a `Node` on the stack, and decide what to do based on `instanceof`. Another is to create a `Task` class, and use `Stack<Task>`.